# yum: install local RPMs and all local dependencies

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf

I have my locally generated `rpm` packages (the main package and its dependencies) located in my home directory. The `spec` file defines dependencies. I'd like to install it with a single `yum` or `dnf` command and let it find dependencies in my directory and install them accordingly. I tried `yum`:

```
% yum -y localinstall ~/rpms/mypackage-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

However it complains:

```
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides mypackage-libs(x86-64) = 2.1.1-2.1 needed by mypackage-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or this indicates that I have a bug in my `spec` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yum's error is consistent with `mypackage` requiring sub-package `mypackage-libs` (of the exact same version).  This is a pattern that can work for packages.

However you need to install `libs` first, or both at the same time. For loose rpms, provide both files. As the file names would be by convention very similar, a shell trick useful here is [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```bash
yum localinstall ~/rpms/mypackage{,-libs}-2.1.1-2.1.x86_64.rpm
```

> I'd like to install it with a single yum or dnf command and let it
> find dependencies in my directory and install them accordingly.

yum requires a repo to use a directory (or remote server) of packages in dependency solving. Which will  enable just `yum install mypackage`
Consider creating a custom mirror, with `createrepo` (aka `createrepo_c`) or a higher level software content management solution.

Comment: Thanks for comments! Let me clarify that I understand it right: a) create my custom repository for `mypackage` b) update `/etc/yum.repos.d` to add my new repository

Does that sound right?